# I'm trying to solve the problem based on absolute values, I'm not sure if what I am doing is right.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-||x||}$$from the function I need to find the domain.

And this was my approach:

$$1-||x||\not=0$$

$$||x||^2\not=|-1|^2$$

$$||x||\not=-1$$

$$|x^2|\not=1$$

domain: $x<0$ or $x>0$.

Comment: $x\ne\pm1{}{}{}$

Comment: Are you sure $x$ is a real number? I've usually seen the "double bar" version of abs value used on vectors.

Comment: ooh, I treated the double bar as absolute values being doubled. I'm not really sure if this could be a vector or absolute value. however, is it possible to find domain of the function if we are to treat the double bars as vectors?

Comment: I mean, ||x|| in terms of absolute value means just $|x|$, since the inside will always be positive, and so we don't need the second absolute value bars.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $||x||$ means the absolute value of the absolute value of $x$.

Note that the domain should be $\mathbb{R}$, except for when $1-||x||=0.$ So $||x||=1.$ We just need to check $x=\pm{1}$.
$$||1||=1$$$$||-1||=|1|=1$$

Therefore, the domain is $\mathbb{R}  /(-1, 1)$ (all real numbers besides $-1$ and $1$)